# I am trying to display the output of my addition and subtraction functions into display function

Tags: c++, function, module

I am trying to display the result of my addition and subtraction function when I add or subtract two fractions. However, whenever I enter the two fractions, it does not display the results. It just goes straight to the "Press any key to continue" line. I was wondering if anyone can guide me to the solution. Doing the work for me isn't necessary, but some hints would be of great help. I have been trying to figure this out for some time by looking at my code, using the internet for resources, and looking at my c++ book for a bit of help. I'm certain I am doing something wrong in the display function. Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void info();
void input (int ,int ,int ,int ,int , int,char, char);
int add (int,int,int,int,int,int,char,char);
int subtract(int,int,int,int,int,int,char, char);
void display ();

int main()
{ int num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result, den_result;
  char fraction_char;
  char operation;



info();
input (num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char, operation);
add (num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char, operation);
subtract(num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char,operation);
display ();

    return 0;
}

void info()
{ cout<<"Please follow instructions carefully."<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter your operation like 1/2 + 1/4"<<endl;
   cout<<"You must enter a valid operation."<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter % operator to stop the program (0/1 % 0/1)"<<endl;

}

void input (int num1,int den1,int num2,int den2,int num_result, int den_result,char fraction_char, char operation)
{ cout<<"Please enter your operation."<<endl;
  cin>>num1>>fraction_char>>den1>>num2>>fraction_char>>den2;


}

int add (int num1,int den1,int num2,int den2,int num_result,int den_result,char fraction_char, char operation)
{ int addition_answer;

    if(operation== '+')
   {   num_result = (num1*den2) + (num2*den1);

       den_result = den1*den2;
      addition_answer = num_result/den_result;
   }
  return addition_answer;


}

int subtract(int num1,int den1,int num2,int den2,int num_result,int den_result, char fraction_char, char operation)
{ int subtraction_answer;


    if (operation == '-')
  { num_result = (num1*den2) - (num2*den1);
    den_result = den1*den2;
    subtraction_answer= num_result/den_result;

  }
    return subtraction_answer;
}



void display ()

{
  int num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char,operation;
  int fraction_added =  add (num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char,operation);
  int fraction_subtracted = subtract(num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char,operation);



  if (operation== fraction_added)

  {

  cout<<"Your answer is: "<<add;
  }

  else if (operation== fraction_subtracted)
  {
      cout<<"You answer is: "<<subtract;
  }
    add(num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char,operation);
    subtract(num1,den1,num2,den2,num_result,den_result,fraction_char,operation);
}
```

Comment: In display you are using operation without initializing it. Also why are you trying to do calculations in display anyways? display() needs parameters.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The input function does not return any of the variables that it gets from cin. That is because you are passing the function's parameters by value, so it gets a copy of the variables from main but can not change main's variables.

For the input function to be able to change main's variables you must change the parameters so you pass by reference or pointer.

The cout calls don't make much sense: For example, it looks like you get a result in fraction_added but then do not output that result.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have figured it out. :)